# Will etckeeper do auto-commits when PackageKit-hif is used [i.e. Fedora Workstation]?

Tags: fedora, packagekit, etckeeper

> [etckeeper] hooks into package managers like apt to automatically commit changes made to /etc during package upgrades [to a git repository]

Fedora uses `libhif` as a backend for PackageKit tools, such as GNOME Software.  `libhif` doesn't use the command-line package manager, `dnf`, which leads to some confusing situations.  E.g. PackageKit and dnf don't share caches, at least for the moment.

Question: If I install etckeeper on Fedora, will it make the automatic commits before/after package installs/upgrades, if these actions are performed using PackageKit as opposed to using dnf on the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment.  Using `etckeeper-1.18.3-2.fc24.noarch`, upgrading packages with PackageKit leaves uncommitted changes in `/etc`.  (`etckeeper vcs diff`).

This is after setting `HIGHLEVEL_PACKAGE_MANAGER=dnf`, though I'm not sure how it makes a difference.

`etckeeper-dnf` package is installed automatically, but that's the only other etckeeper package available in Fedora.  (Apart from etckeeper-bzr, which allows to use `bzr` instead of the default `git`).